# Why does VS 2019 keep overriding my warnings setting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, project-settings

Kinda stumped on this one.  I'm using a library from GitHub and it's throwing tons of warnings, so I went into the project's build settings, chose 'All Configurations' and chose `0` for the warning level under 'Errors and Warnings'.  This added the following to the project file:

```xml
<WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
```

Rebuilding and all the warnings went away.

Then on the next build, they came right back! Huh?

Went back into the UI and saw it was set back to `5`!  I checked the project file and it was still at `0` as expected.

To test, I changed the level `2` in the UI, and as expected, the project file updated to this instantly:

```xml
<WarningLevel>2</WarningLevel>
```

But then, a few seconds later, the UI again snapped back to 5!  WTF?!?!

I looked around to see if there was any global overrides but didn't find anything, although I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.

Anyone know what's going on? It's really @$#!@ annoying!

Here's my fork of the project if anyone else wants to take a look:

https://github.com/MarqueIV/WpfExtendedToolkit
(Forked from here: https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfExtendedToolkit)

#### Update

I checked out the project on a completely separate Win10 install where I also installed VS 2019 Community for the first time, and the same thing happened... it keeps 'resetting' the warning level, so it's something somewhere in the project itself I would think.

Comment: Maybe it builds a buildtask that runs on every build and set that warninglevel. Any unexpected imports in that project file?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  I added a link to the project if you wanna take a look. It's a popular one that I forked.

Comment: Nothing in those projects that jump out at me. Strange.

Comment: First eliminate any extensions - have you confirmed the same happens with no extensions enabled?

Comment: To disable the warnings for a project, you could add this to your project `#pragma warning disable`.  Optionally specify the warning numbers to be ignored.  ( [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning) )

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14490

Comment: Awesome find!  Post that in an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: "[Automatically find latent bugs in your code with .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/automatically-find-latent-bugs-in-your-code-with-net-5/)" says that you should set `AnalysisLevel` to 0 to disable all warnings.

Comment: I don't want to support such an answer, the agile hack they used is too fugly to be treated in a neutral tone.  Just upvote the comment so users can see it and the question avoids the roomba.

Comment: "...avoids the Roomba!"   Thanks for that laugh today. :) Done as you wished.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this isn't an 'answer' per se, but here's a workaround, at least for now to shut up the warnings.

In addition to `WarningLevel`, you have to also set the `AnalysisLevel` and `RunAnalyzersDuringBuild` by adding the following to your project.

```xml
<WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
<AnalysisLevel>none</AnalysisLevel>
<RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
```

That stops the warnings.

Still, there shouldn't be a case where something overrides `WarningLevel` which is why I'm posting this, but not marking it as the accepted answer. It isn't. It's a temporary, 'blunt-hammer' fix until they restore the behavior to the pre-.NET 5.0 way of it working. Let's hope that was an oversight and not an intentional change.

Comment: As a reference, a link to the blog from microsoft: [Automatically find latent bugs in your code with .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/automatically-find-latent-bugs-in-your-code-with-net-5/)